# Flutter camera have a lag on the ui before starting to record a video

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and trying to build a cemera app to record video. However, when I implement the following code, my app lags and freeze for half a second before the it starts recording a video, how do I eliminate the freeze? Below is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class CameraPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraPageState createState() => _CameraPageState();
}

class _CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage> {
  bool _isLoading = true;
  bool _isRecording = false;
  late CameraController _cameraController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initCamera();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _initCamera() async {
    final cameras = await availableCameras();
    final front = cameras.firstWhere(
        (camera) => camera.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front);
    _cameraController = CameraController(front, ResolutionPreset.max);
    await _cameraController.initialize();
    setState(() => _isLoading = false);
  }

  Future<void> _recordVideo() async {
    if (_isRecording) {
      final file = await _cameraController.stopVideoRecording();
      setState(() => _isRecording = false);
      final route = MaterialPageRoute(
        fullscreenDialog: true,
        builder: (_) => VideoPage(filePath: file.path),
      );
      Navigator.push(context, route);
    } else {
      await _cameraController.prepareForVideoRecording();
      await _cameraController.startVideoRecording();
      setState(() => _isRecording = true);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isLoading) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Center(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            CameraPreview(_cameraController),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                child: Icon(_isRecording ? Icons.stop : Icons.circle),
                onPressed: () => _recordVideo(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}

class VideoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String filePath;

  const VideoPage({Key? key, required this.filePath}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPageState createState() => _VideoPageState();
}

class _VideoPageState extends State<VideoPage> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future _initVideoPlayer() async {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(widget.filePath));
    await _videoPlayerController.initialize();
    await _videoPlayerController.setLooping(true);
    await _videoPlayerController.play();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Preview'),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.check),
            onPressed: () {
              print('do something with the file');
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initVideoPlayer(),
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

At first I thought this is because the camera need to be prepared, and hence the hang/wait, so I tried putting the prepareForVideoRecording line right after the camera controller is initiated, but it doesnt solve the problem unfortunately.